# Merge two files together by awk

Tags: awk, merge, match

I thought I understand how to merge files. Could you help me tell, where is the problem in my script?

INPUT:

file1

```
 c.001A>C   11  p.His103    A
 c.000A>C   12  p.Thr102    E
 c.111A>C   12  p.Thr102    D
```

file2

```
APC 5   112835056   ENST00000507379 13  c.001A>C    p.Val599Phe  
APC 5   112819143   ENST00000257430 9   c.1111G  p.G371X
APC 5   1128395514  ENST00000257430 15  c.001A>C     p.Glu1309AspfsT
APC 5   112838773   ENST00000257430 15  c.000A>C    p.Gln1062Ter
```

OUTPUT:

```
APC 5   112835056   ENST00000507379 13  c.001A>C    p.Val59   c.001A>C  11  p.His103    A
APC 5   1128395514  ENST00000257430 15  c.001A>C    p.Glu1    c.001A>C  11  p.His103    A
APC 5   112838773   ENST00000257430 15  c.000A>C    p.Gln10   c.000A>C  12  p.Thr102    E
```

So far, the following `awk` line has been attempted:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1FS$2FS$3FS$4; next} {if ($6 in a) print $0, a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

I would like to merge the file1 column1 with file2 column6 and print only match and all columns from both files. But it not working.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please more elaborate 6th column's output more? How it is reduced? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok to use GNU tools, you merge both files with `join`, `sort` and `column` commands:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 6 -o "2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 1.3 1.4" <(sort file1) <(sed 's/ \+/ /g' file2 | sort -k6) | column -t
APC  5  112838773   ENST00000257430  15  c.000A>C  p.Gln1062Ter     p.Thr102  E
APC  5  1128395514  ENST00000257430  15  c.001A>C  p.Glu1309AspfsT  p.His103  A
APC  5  112835056   ENST00000507379  13  c.001A>C  p.Val599Phe      p.His103  A
```

`join` command merge files based on first column of file1 and 6th column of file2. This command expects sorted input on both files which is done with `<(...)`. The option `-o` lists all column you want to display.

Note the `sed` command removesduplicate white spaces in order to have the right column number for `sort` (on the 2nd file).

At last `column -t` is nicely displaying fields in a column style.